# Как сделать интерактивный баннер?

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. У меня к вам вот такой вопрос. Хочу сделать интерактивный баннер (такой же как на сайте http://www.chulakov.ru/work/secretsmagic_sheep/ с кроликом). Подскажите, кто знает, в какой программе это делается? Можно любой баннер, главное, чтобы человек мог что-то изменять в самом баннере при наведении мышки.

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего, это сделано во флеше. Во всяком случае, подобное делается во флеше. Например, Adobe Flash CS5 (можно триал скачать на adobe.com). Плюс к этому почти наверняка придется немного написать кода на ActionScript (скриптовый язык флеша).